# Properties of Topologically Ordered States

Tags: condensed-matter, gauge-theory, topological-order, topological-phase

From what I've read so far, all topologically ordered states seem to possess the following properties:

- Gapped excitations with fractionalized statistics (anyons)
- Gauge theory structure (which may be "emergent")
- Long range entanglement

For example, the toric code has a $Z_2$ gauge theory structure, and the gapped excitations (e and m particles, which correspond to odd plaquette and star operators, respectively) have semionic statistics with respect to each other ($\theta=\pi/2$).

I'm trying to understand how these properties relate. It seems clear that the presence of a gauge theory structure implies long-range entanglement, since this allows for "massive" superposition in the ground state wavefunction. It also makes sense that anyons need this long-range entanglement. Elsewise, the notion of two anyons "sensing" each other, regardless of their distance, does not make sense. So ultimately, I think it holds that:

Anyons $\rightarrow$ Gauge Theory $\leftrightarrow$ Long-range entanglement

Does this hold the other way? Namely, if a system has gapped excitations and a gauge theory structure/long-range entanglement, does this always imply the existence of anyons?